# Bash module load function not working as expected

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sh, condor

I have a batch script that I eventually want to execute on a cluster via condor_submit. The script needs to load some module via "module load matlab/R2020a". However nothing works.

The script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
module load cudnn/8.2.0-cu11.x
module load cuda/11.2
module load matlab/R2020a
echo $PATH
echo $SHELL
#Check matlab version 
echo_and_run() { echo "$*" ; "$@" ; }
matlab -e | grep "MATLAB="
echo_and_run matlab -e | grep "MATLAB="  
...
setup input etc. 
...
echo_and_run matlab -nodisplay -batch "......matlab commands"
```

When I run it from my home shell it gives me:

```
...
/bin/bash
MATLAB=/is/software/matlab/linux/R2014a
MATLAB=/is/software/matlab/linux/R2014a
...
```

Which is both not correct.
When executing this in my local shell ( source ./scriptname.sh) The output is even more confusing:

```
...
/bin/bash
MATLAB=/is/software/matlab/linux/R2020a
MATLAB=/is/software/matlab/linux/R2014a
...
```

So the matlab version updates, but only for the non "echo_and_run" execution (the first call). In the actual call it also is the default 2014 version.

What in the world is going on? I checked the $PATH variables and they are identically to my running shell. I tried sourcing ~/.bashrc at the top of the script, no difference. When I type "type module" I can see that it is a function:

```
module is a function
module () 
{ 
    _module_raw "$@" 2>&1
}
```

Some older posts mention, that I should either run with "source" or "." (for sh) but I cannot do that, since the script is called by condor_submit eventually. Or I should find the file that defines module. However I do not know what other file (besides ~/.bashrc) that could be.

Old post: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/194893/why-cant-i-load-modules-while-executing-my-bash-script-but-only-when-sourcing

### Edit

I am currently trying everything locally (in the login shell) which could be different from the execution shell, but even here I get this weird behaviour.

Edit II:

```
    + type -a _module_raw
_module_raw is a function
_module_raw () 
{ 
    unset _mlshdbg;
    if [ "${MODULES_SILENT_SHELL_DEBUG:-0}" = '1' ]; then
        case "$-" in 
            *v*x*)
                set +vx;
                _mlshdbg='vx'
            ;;
            *v*)
                set +v;
                _mlshdbg='v'
            ;;
            *x*)
                set +x;
                _mlshdbg='x'
            ;;
            *)
                _mlshdbg=''
            ;;
        esac;
    fi;
    unset _mlre _mlIFS;
    if [ -n "${IFS+x}" ]; then
        _mlIFS=$IFS;
    fi;
    IFS=' ';
    for _mlv in ${MODULES_RUN_QUARANTINE:-};
    do
        if [ "${_mlv}" = "${_mlv##*[!A-Za-z0-9_]}" -a "${_mlv}" = "${_mlv#[0-9]}" ]; then
            if [ -n "`eval 'echo ${'$_mlv'+x}'`" ]; then
                _mlre="${_mlre:-}${_mlv}_modquar='`eval 'echo ${'$_mlv'}'`' ";
            fi;
            _mlrv="MODULES_RUNENV_${_mlv}";
            _mlre="${_mlre:-}${_mlv}='`eval 'echo ${'$_mlrv':-}'`' ";
        fi;
    done;
    if [ -n "${_mlre:-}" ]; then
        eval `eval ${_mlre}/usr/bin/tclsh8.6 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/modulecmd.tcl bash '"$@"'`;
    else
        eval `/usr/bin/tclsh8.6 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/modulecmd.tcl bash "$@"`;
    fi;
    _mlstatus=$?;
    if [ -n "${_mlIFS+x}" ]; then
        IFS=$_mlIFS;
    else
        unset IFS;
    fi;
    unset _mlre _mlv _mlrv _mlIFS;
    if [ -n "${_mlshdbg:-}" ]; then
        set -$_mlshdbg;
    fi;
    unset _mlshdbg;
    return $_mlstatus
}
```

Comment: How and where is `_module_raw` implemented?

Comment: The server where you have a login shell almost certainly has a different configuration than the nodes where your scheduled jobs get executed.

Comment: No idea. How do i find out?

Comment: But i am starting this script currently from my local console with either "source ..." or just ./scriptname.sh

Comment: `type -a _module_raw`

Comment: Its a long function. Should i post it completely?

Comment: Canonically, what we want is a [mre] -- the shortest possible code we can run ourselves without changes to see the same problem (modify to test fixes, etc). Right now, we _can't_ cause the same problem ourselves, so it's not "reproducible". Posting too much may make it no longer "minimal", but it's still a step _towards_ satisfying those requirements; the more you can cut it down while still being able to test that it causes the same problem, the better off you are wrt being in a place where we can help.

Comment: Is `matlab` an alias or function? How do you conclude that your script doesn't work?

Comment: BTW, it looks to me like this `module` framework is an open-source tool from https://modules.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: matlab is an alias to either clustersoftwarepath/matlab/linux/R2020a/bin/matlab' or 'clustersoftwarepath/matlab/linux/R2014a/bin/matlab    I say my script does not work, because i need the 2020a version of matlab, but it is not loaded and i cannot use the -batch functionality of matlab in 2014.

Comment: BTW, when you want to log things before running them, _in general_ `set -x` is the best way to do that; you can customize its output by changing `PS4` to contain filename, line number, etc.

Comment: Running `set -x` at the very top of your file will let you see which shell commands `module load matlab/R2020a` invokes, which is _particularly_ likely to be interesting. If it sets up matlab as an alias, f/e, that would explain the problem (aliases only work in interactive shells, not in scripts, by default). `PS4=':${BASH_SOURCE}:$LINENO+'` is a sane starting place.

Comment: Neat. didnt know about set -x. 
Also that might get me closer to an explaination, since matlab is an alias in both cases and the module load function seems to change the alias. Is there no way to use it from a seperate script?

Comment: ...note that there's a length limit on PS4 prefixes, so if the whole source filename is too much you might need `PS4=':${BASH_SOURCE##*/}:$LINENO+'` to trim the path off the filename.

Comment: ...if you need to turn aliases on in scripts, and your shell is bash (you tagged both it and `sh`, but they're two very different shells), `shopt -s expand_aliases` is perhaps the easy way to get there.

Comment: ...okay, so `_module_raw` runs a TCL program that's expected to spit out shell code, and then executes whatever that shell program emitted. (1) Ew; (2) Because we don't know what code the TCL program emits when given `matlab/R2020a` as an argument, it's not as helpful a thing to know as one might have hoped.

Comment: (also, the shell wrapper running that TCL code is badly written; doubling up `eval`s is basically never a good idea, and using legacy pre-POSIX command substitution syntax is a fairly serious code smell; I realize you didn't write the code doing this environment setup, but... take this as advice that it's not to be emulated).

Answer (score 0):

Provided script output does not help to understand if there is an issue at the environment modules level.

Adding a `module list` command in your script after the 3 `module load` commands may help to determine if the `module` function has properly loaded your environment or not.

In some situations, like when running script on a cluster through a batch scheduler, it is good to source the module initialization script at the start of such script to ensure the `module` function is defined. It seems that you are running on a Debian-like system, so the initialization script may be sourced with:

```bash
. /usr/share/modules/init/bash
```